# How can I limit ffmpeg memory usage

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I am using ffmpeg to convert a 1080p video to MP4 using this command in PHP.

```
$command = FFMPEG.' -i ' . $src . ' -sameq -strict -2 -vcodec libx264 -ar 22050 -y ' . $dest.'.mp4 2>&1'; 
exec($command,$output,$status);
```

The problem is that the process uses a lot of memory ~1600MB, which is not allowed by my server so ffmpeg gets terminated. Can I limit the memory usage of ffmpeg to about 600-700MB?

Any help is greatly appreciated...

Comment: Related [Is there any way to limit FFmpeg’s memory usage?](https://superuser.com/q/1570417/169199)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not about PHP. It's about how to limit FFMPEG memory usage.

Short answer no!

Look here: http://hwdmediashare.co.uk/forum/27-development-customisation/54700-limit-ffmpeg-memory-usage

Comment: So what other options do I have to achieve the goal (converting 1080p .mov file to same quality mp4) ??

Comment: @Khan, seems you just want to transformat and not necessarily rencode the video. So you can do it with very little memory requirement. See my answer above.

Comment: Link is dead : That's why it is strongly adviced to copy the content that answer the question in SO...

Comment: Forum is down; archive link [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160507005916/http://hwdmediashare.co.uk/forum/27-development-customisation/54700-limit-ffmpeg-memory-usage).

Answer (score 4):

It would be the video codec which is mainly responsible for the high memory use.

So it's the encoder whose memory use needs to be addressed, not FFmpeg directly. I'm not sure how to fix `x264`'s memory use, but I tried the newer x26**5** and in my case it's only using 1.6 GB, while libx264 was failing by asking more than the 2 GB memory limit (per process, on 32-bit systems).

So, what worked for me was to use:

```
ffmpeg -i input -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v hevc -x265-params crf=23 out.mp4
```

(Omitting parameters to take care of the audio.)

But the general approach is to try other encoders. I was going to try mpeg4 and vp9 if x265 didn't work, maybe others. If none of that works, then further options include looking at the encoders' settings (though nothing obvious and directly relevant to memory use shows up):

```
ffmpeg -h encoder=mpeg4
```

---

Update: actually, it turned out that YouTube doesn't accept HEVC (aka H.265) yet (and it only let me know after the upload finished). So, like I suggested above, I went for VP9, doing a pilot run with the first 50 frames this time. I used settings similar to [a guide](http://wiki.webmproject.org/ffmpeg/vp9-encoding-guide) I found (the *Constant quality* settings, though I should have used more of their suggested parameters):

```
ffmpeg.exe -i <input> -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v libvpx-vp9 -pass 1 -b:v 0 -crf 20 -f webm pass1.webm

ffmpeg.exe -i <input> -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v libvpx-vp9 -pass 2 -b:v 0 -crf 20 -f webm pass2.webm
```

(Note that `pass1.webm` will be almost empty.)

Also note that two passes are preferred whenever possible. It's better on all fronts, including faster encoding overall.

With these settings, a 73-second clip at 4K resolution took about 16 hours to encode — that's using one core, as I forgot to specify `-threads`. While slow, FFmpeg's memory use only went up to about 0.6 GB. The resulting file was 300 MB, and I can't see any loss of quality compared to uncompressed frames (so `-crf 20` might have been a bit too low).

Answer (score 0):

The truth is video encoding a CPU and memory intensive job. If you want to do it you need to give the requisite memory for it.

Since you want to convert a 1080p .mov to a .mp4 of same quality I am assuming you jsut want to change the format of the file and not reencode.

ffmpeg -i input.mov -acodec copy -vcodec copy out.mp4

will do it in a jiffy and without any of the memory overheads

If you want your audio codec only changed don't give the acodec part.

If the input video codec does not work for you [so copy is not an option] try doing mpeg4 encoding for vcodec. Cheaper to encode there but I cannot assure you it will fit in your memory requirements always.

Comment: Thanks av501! the command do work for mov file. but my input file may be in any format( flv, mp4, mov, wmv etc). Actually I am trying to convert any user provided video to both mp4 and ogv format without any quality loss. Is that possible ? here is my command for ogv : ffmpeg -i input.wmv -c:v libtheora -q:v 7 -c:a libvorbis -q:a 5 -y output.ogv

Comment: If the output format allows the codecs that the input file has [codecs] then yes it is allowed. So mov => mp4 is 100% possible because they are pretty much the same format [minor differences]. [mp4 3gp mov are pretty much one and the same]   wmv => mp4 depends on the codec you have in the wmv.   flv to mp4 will also work when flv has h.264. So atleast this should work for such files. For other files you will have to transcode.