# FFMPEG memory limit issue

Tags: php, memory, ffmpeg

Using bash, I can execute this:

> ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf \"scale=720:trunc(ow/a/2)*2\" -c:v libx264 output.mp4

But, when I do this:

`<?php shell_exec("ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf \"scale=720:trunc(ow/a/2)*2\" -c:v libx264 output.mp4");?>`

I get this error:

> x264 [error]: malloc of size 238336 failed
>   Video encoding failed

Comment: What is the memory_limit setting in your php.ini?

Comment: ffmpeg can output a lot of data when it is run, and php is keeping it to return it to your script.  If you pipe the output to /dev/null (or NUL on Windows), you won't see the output, but it won't have the problem.  You're not examining the output anyway, so it would be easier to just switch the "shell_exec" to a "system" call.

Comment: I tried 'system' but nothing changes. Also memory_limit is 512M right now.

Comment: Short [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12390682/how-can-i-limit-ffmpeg-memory-usage) is: you can do nothing about memory consumption of ffmpeg.